# Use entry input as variable with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a program that needs the user to input data. This code that I wrote does not work or it says None in the console. It should print the user input. I know that I might have to use the .get() function but I don't know where. Any help would be great

```
def settings():
    Settings = Toplevel(root)
    Settings.title("ad.lo exporter Settings")
    Settings.geometry("295x132")

    global Pname
    Label(Settings, text="Publisher name (abbreviation)").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Pname = Entry(Settings).grid(row=0, column=1)

    global UNitemailinp
    Label(Settings, text="Ad-Unit email address").grid(row=1, column=0)
    UNitemailinp = Entry(Settings).grid(row=1, column=1)

    global UNitpasswordinp
    Label(Settings, text="Ad-Unit password").grid(row=2, column=0)
    UNitpasswordinp = Entry(Settings).grid(row=2, column=1)

    global UNitsiteinp
    Label(Settings, text="Ad-Unit website").grid(row=3, column=0)
    UNitsiteinp = Entry(Settings).grid(row=3, column=1)

    addrecordBTN = Button(Settings, text="Add record", command=addrecord).grid(row=4, column=0)
    removerecordBTN = Button(Settings, text="Remove record", command=removerecord).grid(row=4, column=1)
    
def addrecord():
        print("added record")
        print(Pname)#not printing the record
```

Comment: Change `Pname = Entry(Settings).grid(row=0, column=1)` to `Pname = Entry(Settings)` and `Pname.grid(row=0, column=1)`. Then you can use `print(Pname.get())`

Comment: `your_entry_var = entry.ge()` 
`your_label.config(text=your_entry_var)`

Comment: The first comment solves my problem thank you